# weakSelf on queue calling method that use self inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Is it ok if i do something like:

```
  -(void)example{
       __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

       dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("q_getRestaurants", NULL);
       dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf doSomething];
           });
       });
    }



   -(void)doSomething{
       //can i use self inside this method????
       self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   }
```

The thing is that i wanna know if there is ok if i use self inside the do something method that is being called from a queue that has a weakSelf call.

Comment: Are you saying that during the "//Call something from server" section you want to reference `self`?

Comment: no, the thing is if i can call [weakSelf doSomething] and use **self** inside the **doSomething** method

Comment: Yes, you can.  Inside a method (other than init) you are guaranteed that self is always a valid value.  If self had been deallocated, and weakSelf automatically set to nil, then `[weakSelf doSomething];` will instead do nothing and not actually invoke doSomething.

Comment: This question could be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339490/arc-self-and-blocks/

Comment: @David: Well, you are guaranteed that `self` (like all parameters) points to a valid value *at the beginning of* a method. Not later.

Comment: @newacct since assigning to self is only allowed in init (the compiler gives an error anywhere else), you have to really work to invalidate self within a method.

Comment: @David: Assigning to `self` is not the issue. The issue is that the object pointed to by `self` can be deallocated.

Comment: @newacct in an ARC world, I think you'd have to be doing something incredibly bizarre for self to be invalidated during a method invocation.  I made an extremely contrived test here http://pastebin.com/wk86FYmx and self is still valid, even after deleting all known references (other than the method invocation)  Perhaps you can come up with an example?

Comment: @David: It doesn't have to be bizarre or contrived. Here is a very reasonable situation where the object pointed to by `self` becomes invalid in the middle of the method: http://pastebin.com/fZkXuzYR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You're good there. Only variables inside the block itself are retained.

Comment: So, no matters if I use self inside the **doSomething** method if I call it from the weakSelf pointer?

Comment: Correct. Though you might want to consider making a strongSelf inside the block to ensure the weakSelf doesn't get nilled out. Depends on what self is though. If it's an appDelegate or something you don't need to worry since it's not going anywhere.